# How to send var to view from event listener in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to send var to view from event listener in symfony2 but I am stacked.

1) Is this possible?

2) What kernel event to use (kernel.view or kernel.request)?

3) Finally how to send some var to view?

My best guess is that I have to extend return from controller and then to let controller do his job.

I need to send some array of objects (entities).

Comment: So, you need to include a variable defined in an EventListener (suppose Request?) to each any views you are calling from any controller?

Comment: @Touki yes that is correct

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I see several ways to handle this.

## Adding a global variable from a `kernel.request` listener

The idea is to add a global variable straight after the `kernel.request` event.

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    class: Acme\FooBundle\Listener\MyListener
    arguments:
        - @twig
    tags:
        -
            name: kernel.event_listener
            event: kernel.request
            method: onKernelRequest
```

<kbd>**MyListener**</kbd>

```
class MyListener
{
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $myVar = 'foo'; // Process data

        $this->twig->addGlobal('myvar', $myVar);
    }
}
```

You can now use it at any time by doing

```
{{ myvar }}
```

---

## From a `kernel.view` listener

First, you need to understand when `kernel.view` is called. It's only called when the return of the controller [is not an instance of Response object](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.16/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L120).
That said, doing

```
// Acme/FooBundle/FooController#fooAction

return $this->render();
```

returns a [Response object](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.16/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L102), so `kernel.view` is not called.

### Defining controllers

The idea is to make all controller returns an array of data, just like `@Template` requirements.

```
// Acme/FooBundle/FooController#fooAction

return array(
    'template' => 'AcmeFooBundle:Foo:foo.html.twig',
    'data' => array(
        'entity' => $entity
    )
);
```

### Defining the service

Since you already have your service definition, you just need to add some requirements in your service declaration.
You need the `@templating` service to render the data.
You need to set itself as a `kernel.view` listener

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    acme_foo.my_listener:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Listener\MyListener
        arguments:
            - @templating
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.request
                method: onKernelRequest
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                event: kernel.view
                method: onKernelView
```

### Creating the service

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Listener/MyListener.php

use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;

class MyListener
{
    protected $templating;
    protected $myVar;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function getMyVar()
    {
        return $this->myVar;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->myVar = ""; // Process MyVar data
    }

    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $result = $event->getControllerResult();

        if (null === $this->myVar || !isset($result['template']) || !isset($result['data'])) {
            return;
        }

        $data = array_merge($result['data'], array('myvar' => $this->myVar));
        $rendered = $this->templating->render($result['template'], $data);

        $event->setResponse(new Response($rendered));
    }
}
```

And there you are. The listener is creating a new response, adding your custom definition of `myvar` to any template rendered by him.

---

## From a TWIG extension

An alternative is to [create a TWIG extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html). In the following example, I'm assuming the `MyListener` definition is the same as above.

### Defining services

As per the documentation given above, you just have to create a simple extension class.

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    acme_foo.my_listener:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Listener\MyListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
    acme_foo.my_extension:
        class: Acme\FooBundle\Extension\MyExtension
        arguments:
            - @acme_foo.my_listener
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

### Defining the service

Just like in documentation, we'll create a simple function.

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Extension/MyExtension.php

use Acme\FooBundle\Listener\MyListener;

class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $listener;

    public function __construct(MyListener $listener)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_extension';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'myvar' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getMyVar')
        );
    }

    public function getMyVar()
    {
        return $this->listener->getMyVar();
    }
}
```

### Usage

Then you can use it in any view by doing

```
{{ myvar() }}
```

---

## From a common controller

I don't like this idea, but this is an alternative. You just have to create a `BaseController` which will override the default `render` method.

```
// Acme/FooBundle/Controller/BaseController.php

abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        $parameters = array_merge(
            $parameters,
            array(
                'myvar' => $this->get('my_listener')->getMyVar()
            )
        );

        return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question with the twig extension case : the twig function will call `getMyVar()` which contains : `return $this->listener->getMyVar();`. But the listener doesn't have this method right ?

Comment: @AdrienG It's not given in my exampe, but this is just a getter to expose the computed var, which can be easily implemented

Comment: This does not work for anything computed within your typical `onKernelResponse` method; like the one you return in `getSubscribedEvents()`, even if you store the variable as a class member and try and retrieve it later.

Comment: Since Twig 1.21, for adding a global variable from a kernel.request listener, you need to update the global variable if it exists, instead you will have a deprecation notice.

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative method here that I've had to do. I wanted to get some data, run it through `json_encode()`, then *add* that as a JavaScript variable to the response. Here's what I ended up doing.

I'm subscribing to `kernel.response`:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse'
    ];
}

public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    /** -- SNIP -- Cutting out how I get my serialised data **/
    $serialized = json_encode($data);

    /** Shove it into the response as some JS at the bottom **/
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($event->getResponse()->getContent());
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    $node = $dom->createElement('script', "var data = $serialized;");

    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild($node);

    $event->getResponse()->setContent($dom->saveHTML());
}
```

This is *one* way of doing it. Honestly, I don't like *any* of the methods described on this page. There should be a better way, but there isn't. This is what I'm using, though, and it works well. Just make sure you don't call your variable "data"; use something that won't be taken up elsewhere and preferably shove it in it's own `(function() { }` JS namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to pass variables directly to view, but you can change response object, with `kernel.response` event listener. Take a look how symfony debug toolbar injects bottom bar, you could use similar technique.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L106

Comment: No, Symfony injects this toolbar by tweaking the `Response`, hence, TWIG has already been rendered

Comment: That's true, but it may work depending on OP needs. You can have placeholder in twig template and parse later it with listener.